# how to implement an url seen test / cache across multiple crawlers and maintain a good performance?

Tags: java, mysql, database, caching, web-crawler

Currently I am developing a small webcrawler for private testing purpose.

My basic setup is like this:

```
-2 Computers do the crawling (small ram)  
-1 Computer is the main "Database" (big ram).
```

My primary question is how to properly implement a URL seen test across multiple crawlers?

If I only had 1 crawler I would implement a bloom filter in java, but I got stuck on how to do this when you have "**infinite**" crawlers - since they needed to be "synchronized"? So there needs to be a central cache or something, and how does it stay fast?

Querying MySQL with millions of rows after some time may be really slow...

Comment: They don't have to be perfectly synchronized. Think about it - if you add a URL to the cache on crawler 1, and then crawler 2 doesn't see it for a few seconds, the worst that can happen is they both crawl the same page (which is something that could happen already).

Comment: Yes, but shouldn't i try to avoid as many duplicate crawlings of a url to maintain a good speed?

Comment: Also, why do you think querying a table with millions of rows will be slow?

Comment: I read an article where somebody used MySQL as a cache and when you add URLs to your queue, it checks each url against the cache.

Comment: I think some kind of message queue would help. For example, RabbitMQ. But in this case you need something like crawler manager to process crawler results and place tasks for crawler in queue.

Comment: I use RabbitMQ for dispatching urls that need to be crawled to the crawlers. But how could i use it as "cache"?